# Dependency 'androidx.activity:activity:1.8.0' requires libraries and applications that depend on it

Tags: java, android, sdk

Someone help me with this please. I dont even use this dependency => androidx.activity:activity:1.8.0.

I am new to Android SDK but this pretty much ruins my whole learning process. I dont even have this dependency in my build.gradle (app) file, wth?

Google finds nothing on this matter. My compileSdk and targetSdk are set to 33 - still nothing, setting it to 34 it throws tantrum.

I'm desperate, I just added a button to my view...

EDIT: Does not matter if I create a new project or rebuild the gradle, it still throws this. No matter what.

Error:
An issue was found when checking AAR metadata:

1. Dependency 'androidx.activity:activity:1.8.0' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-33.

   Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
   plugin 7.4.2 is 33.

   Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
   plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
   compileSdkVerion of at least 34.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).

Comment: If you are not using the dependency, just remove it (from your `build.gradle` file)

Comment: And for future reference, a compiler doesn't throw tantrums, it throws error messages. Usually those contain useful information.

Comment: Please post a screenshot or copy of your stack trace, project structure and other relevant information. It will help us to help you.

Comment: No screenshots of text, put the text directly in your question.

Comment: @PrajjwalSrivastav For more details why not to use screenshots in Stackoverflow please read the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Comment: Also, that's not the _entire_ error message.  You really do need the whole thing.

Comment: Thank you for advices, I had to set only compileSdk to 34 setting both did not work.

Comment: This question was complete enough to answer. Why was it closed? I disagree with the idea that it needs debugging details. Obviously Android Studio is showing a new error.

Comment: The solution that worked for for me is to use material library 1.9.0 instead of 1.10.0:
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
 found here: https://codeforfun.jp/android-studio-an-issue-was-found-when-checking-aar-metadata-error/